# How can I define my date column in this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I need to use the ggplot2 function but it's not working since x variable isn't defined in:

```
price <- Ad(to.monthly(MRK))

           Daily % Returns
1990-01-02              NA
1990-01-03        1.577301
1990-01-04       -1.577301
1990-01-05       -2.088409
1990-01-08        1.290307
1990-01-09       -0.804477

ggplot(price, aes(x = time(price), y = price, geom_line(color = "darkgreen"), labs(x="Year", y= "Stock Price")
```

What is wrong here and how can I define my dates as the x variable and the "daily % returns" as my y variable?

I am new to R and find it all very difficult, so any help is really appreciated!

Comment: There is no price variable in the data sample you gave in the question. And also the first argument for `ggplot()` needs to be a dataframe object. The x y axis have to be one of the variables in the dataframe you give in the ggplot function as the first argument. You can try to read the documentation of the function first : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.5/topics/ggplot . And learn some ggplot example code.

Comment: Rather than a table of your data, it may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you more. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. The first argument to ggplot must be the dataframe.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~daily, ~returns,
  "1990-01-02",       15,
  "1990-01-03",      -15,
  "1990-01-04",       -2,
  "1990-01-05",       12
  )

df <- df %>% mutate(daily = as.Date(daily))

ggplot(df, aes(x = daily, y = returns)) + 
  geom_line()
```